# Не отправляется форма

Tags: jquery, form

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулась с такой вот проблемой. Написала форму и код отправки ее. Нажимаю, но ничего не происходит. Скажите, где ошибка в коде.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function AjaxFormRequest() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "bdr.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: $('#regForm').serialize(),
                success: function (html) {
                    $(".span8").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<form method='post'  id="regForm"  >
<input name="curcity" type="text" value="Minsk">
<input name="phone" type="text" value="Samsung">
<input onclick="AjaxFormRequest()" id="update"   type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-top:10px;float:right;"/>
</form>
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема или как ее решить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @LovelyCat Не надо ставить восклицательные знаки после каждого предложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключаем `ajax form js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function AjaxFormRequest () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"bdr.php",
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"html",
                data:{
                    someData:$('#regForm').serialize()
                },
                success:
                function(html) {
                    $(".span8").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#sbmtIt').live('click', function() {
            AjaxFormRequest();
        })
    });
</script>

<form method='post'  id="regForm"  >
    <input name="curcity" type="text" value="Minsk">
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="Samsung">
    <input type="submit" id="sbmtIt" value="Submit"
        style="margin-top:10px;float:right;"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас функция объявлена внутри анонимной функции, которая вызывается в ready. она не видна там, где вы ее вызываете, т.е. в onclick. Нужно либо ее выносить в глобальную область, либо (лучше) повесить соответствующий обработчик в javascript'е.

Кроме того, форма у вас будет отправляться дважды. один раз аяксом, второй раз обычно - из html. Обработчик должен быть не на кнопке, а на форме и событие onsubmit. И при вызове вашего обработчика возвращать false или (лучше) вызывать e.preventDefault();

См. вопрос на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967483/form-is-still-submitted-even-though-listener-function-returns-false). Относится к обеим проблемам - там и назначение обработчика и предотвращение двойной отправки формы.

Comment: Хорошо!А что нужно в коде изменить ?Помогите пожалуйста!